# Mac Bluetooth MAP profile

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth, sms

Having heard that Apple has included the Bluetooth MAP profile in iOS 6 I was wondering how I could implement the client side of that on a Mac.

I have spent a while Goggling but I haven't found any documentation on how to use it. Is it built into the OS or will I have to use an external library. (I know there is a Bluetooth API in Mac OS but I don't know if it supports the MAP profile)

Are there any code samples or documentation that I could use?

Comment: hi alex. were you able to make an implementation of this MAP profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not support Bluetooth MAP natively in OSX.  See http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10549 for a list of supported profiles in Mountain Lion. You can create new profiles for OSX, though, within some bounds.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/bluetooth/BT_Develop_BT_Apps/BT_Develop_BT_Apps.html for details.

Since MAP is on top of SPP/RFCOMM (see http://developer.bluetooth.org/KnowledgeCenter/TechnologyOverview/Pages/MAP.aspx), you should be able to implement this profile on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented Bluetooth MAP on Mac OS X in Phone Amego (allowing users to get on-screen SMS).  MAP is built on OBEX which Mac OS X supports. The Bluetooth MAP spec is quite good but takes a while to grok.

You basically create two OBEX sessions: A Message Access Service (MAS) which then registers with the device to receive notifications using the Message Notification Service (MNS). Once you register, the device will open a MNS session with you and notify you of incoming messages. You'll also need to advertise your MNS service using Bluetooth SDP.

Enjoy!
  http://www.sustworks.com/pa_guide/sms.html